# Dbeaver export data wizard does not have "database table" as a target type

Tags: dbeaver, data-export

I am trying to export data from one table to another using DBeaver using the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Data-migration

However, I don't see the "Database table(s)" option when choosing the data transfer target.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

I am on version 22.0 of Dbeaver Lite.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Same issue. Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: I contacted them. Bafflingly, the free Community Edition has this functionality but the *PAID* Lite Edition does not. Thus, you're better off not giving them any money & just using the free version. Which is a pretty odd business approach if you ask me, but I guess "more functional free version it is"...

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [dba.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out (see @J23 comment to the question) that the free Community Edition has this functionality but the paid Lite Edition (that I am using) does not. So the solution is to use the Community Edition.

Comment: Your [previous 'answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586455/10871073) was deleted by a moderator because it is not actually an answer. Neither is this an answer, so I'm flagging it for deletion.

Comment: When a moderator deletes your answer, it means it is not acceptable here. Please do NOT repost that same answer again.

Comment: When a moderator deletes an answer, it probably means they're an OCPD kook, so you have to re-post it. This is both an answer and THE answer: the functionality sought doesn't exist in the SKU being used. There's no other possible answer. To claim otherwise is similar to claiming "There is no month of Febtember" isn't the only possible answer to "How to set my Windows system's date to the 1st of Febtember". Now, if someone were claiming this has turned out to be a useless QUESTION, that's a position with much more merit. In that case, delete the question, not the answer.

Comment: Sorry to keep on this -- but I don't think the question should be deleted either.  The question in @alcalde's analogy may be without merit, but my question is more like "I am trying to change the system date following the instructions in the Control Panel documentation, but the button they are asking us to press isn't there?"

Answer (score -1):

The DBeaver export tool is feature rich. The page you linked is pretty clear about how to do what you are asking.

Choose **DATABASE** as your transfer target.

Use the same database as the target container, if you are moving within the same DB, or choose a different database as the target container.

Follow the instructions on the page you linked to map one table into another, or one column into another, as the case may be.

Comment: As I said in the OP - there is no DATABASE target available.  @Metal450 provided the explanation.

Comment: Sorry about that, you said you didn't see a "Database table(s)" option and I thought you might have been looking for a slightly differently worded option. I also thought I had a paid version, but I find I was mistaken.You should add an answer with @Metal450 info and select it as the correct one.